# Can I determine what app store my iPhone app was downloaded from?

Tags: iphone, localization, internationalization, location

Is there a way for an iPhone app to determine which country's app store it was downloaded from?  I need to disable a feature if the app is being used in certain countries.  NSLocale and MKReverseGeocoder are both options, but both have limitations:

[How to get user's country information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803944/how-to-get-users-country-information)

Basing the app's behavior on which app store it was downloaded from might be a better fit, if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API exposed to do that.  You may consider creating separate targets.  One with all the features, and another, with the specific features removed.  You can then create a separate app ID and sell it within the designated countries that need the alterered version.  Creating separate targets and controlling flow with compile time `if` blocks will allow you to accomplish what you desire while maintaining a single codebase.

See also:

[Building for multiple iPhone targets in XCode](http://finbarrbrady.com/2010/03/building-for-multiple-targets-in-xcode/)