# MKReverseGeocoderDelegate without google maps

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, gps

In my iPhone application I find the latitude and longitude using the location API available. I want to reverse geocode that and get the country code. But without using 3rd party or external API call I would like to get it. When researching I found that MKReverseGeocoderDelegate will be useful for this. But I dont have any requirement to use google maps. I want to know whether my approach is ok to get the current country where user resides.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the MKReverseGeocoder class reference:

> The Google terms of service require
>   that the reverse geocoding service be
>   used in conjunction with a Google map;
>   take this into account when designing
>   your application's user interface.

So, that means you can't use it without using Google Maps (MKMapView).

I recommend looking at an existing SO question that covers what you want to do - [How to get user's country information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803944/how-to-get-users-country-information)

Comment: So that means this approach wont work? http://evilrockhopper.com/2010/01/iphone-development-reverse-geocoding/

Comment: It will, but you will need to use an MKMapView in your app when you use it.

Comment: I've added a link to a another question related to what you want to do to my answer.